# What is the basic principle for a cmos vcc detector circuit?

Tags: power-supply, analog, cmos, chip-design

Most systems that have any controller/firmware need to know when to start powering up. I would imagine this might need a powerup circuit or a detector that trips when we are at an acceptable voltage. What is the basic principle of such a reliable vcc detector? I am starting to learn analog circuit design and would like to know how this is done in cmos in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power on reset circuits are used to trigger the point that a microprocessor can start executing its code without the need to worry about whether the voltage supplies are within their prescribed limits for successful operation.

The basic principle is based on charging a capacitor. The capacitor charges at a rate intentionally slower than what the power supply takes to reach its intended value of 5V or 3V3 or whatever the logic circuit needs to work.

So, the power is up and running, and some short time later the capacitor charge voltage reaches a point that is detected by the "hardware inside the MCU" and the MCU switches on proper and executes its programme.

The charging capacitor is based, in its simplest form, on a resistor from the positive power rail to a capacitor connected to ground. The R x C value might be 100kohm x 1uF which corresponds to a time delay of 100msecs - this is usually enough time. In more precise terms, the RC time of 100msecs represents the cap charging to 62% of the logic supply and a comparator (set to trigger at this voltage or above) instigates the starting gun for the code to begin executing.

There are more complicated features in power-on reset circuits but this is the crux of them.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I get the idea but doesn't the comparator itself need a certain voltage level to work?

Comment: The comparator will be inside the MCU and already be at the correct supply because the delay is longer than the anticipated power-up delay

Answer (score 2):

Rarely does a chip startup need to be overly precise as the design will likely be simulated/designed for a range of temperatures, Voltages and process corners.  What is more likely is the need for certain ranges in dV/dt voltage ramps to ensure the proper sequencing of states during the initial start up phase, but typically there are brown out detectors and /reset assertion during low voltage.  This is typically set by ratio metric means and scaling of W/L of transistors.  So you know that bias generators get turns on first and then output stages.

In general if precision/stability is needed then typically this is accomplished via the design of what is known as bandgap voltage generators that provide a temperature corrected and stable internal voltage reference.  This is done by circuits that examine the relationship between Voltage and Current in a bipolar device (typically a vertical PNP) at varying current densities.  From this they generate PTAT (Proportional To Absolute Temperature) signals and CTAT (Complementary To ....) and PTAT\$^2\$ circuits that are combined with various curvature correction circuits (curvature referring to the response to temperature) to obtain a fairly accurate and stable reference.

Once you have a stable reference you can design circuits that are stable with temperature and voltage supply.

It must be noted that the full bandgap circuits themselves have startup timing requirements as well so they typically don't turn on until the supplies themselves are stable.  But simplified versions are used for a semi-stable reset control the times when that is needed.

Things that need to be watched while coming out of reset are:

- clock start up and stability
- bus drivers - make sure you don't have half awake chips driving bus conflicts.  If bad the power supply may not be able to bring the board up.
- boot code and loading
- internal conflicts and level translations

Comment: Thanks rawbrawb.. My assumption was that there would be an analog circuit that generates a logic level signal that in turn enables the controller that it's OK to start its firmware execution. Isn't there some CMOS circuit that would trip over at lets say 0.8 of rated Vcc so that the logic gates are all reliable?

Comment: 1st paragraph - that's what the reference to /reset means.  it is read as "not reset"